# Как обработать нажатие на InlineKeyboardButton?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Вот я создаю клавиатуру:

```
InlineKeyboardMarkup inlineKeyboard = new(new []
        {
            InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData(text: "1.1", callbackData: "11"),
        });
```

Как мне обработать нажатие с одной единственной кнопки?

Comment: В сообщении будет объект [CallbackQuery](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery)

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey Можете написать пример и через пастебин скинуть пожалуйста?